# T-SQL beginning of week returns incorrect date

Tags: sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I am trying to group a query by the beginning of each week which should be a Monday. I have various references from the internet to get the first day of the week by using the following code:

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @Date), 0)
```

However, this returns an incorrect result as follows:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7

DECLARE @Date DATE
SET @Date = '1/7/2018'

SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @Date), 0)
```

and the result is '1/8/2018'. Obviously the week should not start the day after the date in question.

I have tried setting the day of the week via the "SET DATEFIRST = 1", but this has no impact

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, m.MeasureDT), 0) as StartOfWeek,
    SUM(m.NumeratorVAL) AS Numerator
FROM 
    Database.Schema.Table AS m
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, m.MeasureDT), 0)
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, m.MeasureDT), 0)
```

As a result, each week starts on a Monday, but it includes the prior Sunday. Is there some time setting at a system level or SQL Server level I am missing or is there a flaw in the logic? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the beginning of each week should be Monday, why you are setting it to be Sunday ([`SET DATEFIRST 7`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments))?

Comment: Sorry Andrey, typo should have been 1 as in the note above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your date backward by one day prior to using the regular logic:

```
dateadd(day, -1, m.MeasureDT)
```

Or just do it in one step as explained here: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/normalizing-first-day-week

So off the top of my head, "go back to prior Monday" works out to (dependent on the `@@datefirst` setting):

```
dateadd(day, datepart(weekday, m.MeasureDT) - 1, m.MeasureDT)
```

Unless I'm mistaken, you get to avoid the modular arithmetic since the range of `datepart()` is from 1 to 7, and after offsetting by 1 none of that range falls under zero.

Comment: Thanks shawnT00, this appears to work, I'm just concerned I am missing something and or a lack of understanding of how the datediff is working. Will adding a static -1 be an issue for some years and not others?

Comment: Years will not impact anything. Ultimately the calculation is just "rounding down" to the prior Monday regardless of what year it falls in.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this 

DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @Date), 0)-1
```